# Adding IPv6 address results in deactivated WIFI

Tags: ipv6

I tried:

```
auto wls3
iface wls3 inet manual
iface wls3 inet6 auto
iface wls3 inet6 static
  address new_static_ip
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1
```

after a

```
service network-manager restart
```

wifi isn't working anymore.

I want dhcp and static IPv6

Comment: Do you want `auto` or `static` (which should be `manual`)? They are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way which worked for me: I added 2 files

for if-up: `/etc/network/if-up.d/add-ipv6.sh` content:

```
ip -6 addr add ipv6-address/64 dev wls3
```

and  `/etc/network/if-down.d/add-ipv6.sh` content:

```
ip -6 addr del ipv6-address/64 dev wls3
```